# How to send an array of objects to PHP with Ajax and update the MySQL server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this array of objects:

```
var desks = [];

function Desk(id, name, x, y) {
    var desk = {};
    desk.id = id;
    desk.name = name;
    desk.x = x;
    desk.y = y;
    desks.push(desk);
}
```

And I have a MySQL table with `desk_id`, `desk_name`, `desk_x` and `desk_y` columns.
When I click a button I want to update the values in the table with the Desk objects.

Here's basically what I'm trying achieve:

JS

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "phpfile.php",
        data: desks
    })
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    require "../db.php";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $desks = $_POST("desks");
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($desks); $i++) {
        $sql = "UPDATE desks SET desk_x=$desks[i]->x WHERE desk_id=$desks[i]->id";
        $conn->query($sql);
        $sql = "UPDATE desks SET desk_y=$desks[i]->y WHERE desk_id=$desks[i]->id";
        $conn->query($sql);
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

I don't know whats wrong with it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `data: desks` isn't going to send the data like you think (look at the request in Network tab of developer tools). Also `$_POST("desks")`, `$_POST` is an array not a function: `$_POST["desks"]`

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: I'm running this on my local machine, yes jQuery is included and I'll check developer toold

Comment: Also, instead of `var desk = {};
desk.id = id;
desk.name = name;
desk.x = x;
desk.y = y;` , you can just declare the object values like so: `var desk = { id: id, name: name, x: x, y: y };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the stringify the array when you send it.

**JS**

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "phpfile.php",
        data: { "desks" : JSON.stringify(desks) }
    })
});
```

**PHP**

```
$desks = json_decode($_POST["desks"]);

foreach($desks as $key => $value) {
    $sql = "UPDATE desks SET desk_x=".$value->x.",desk_y=".$value->y." WHERE desk_id=".$value->id;
    $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this
**JS**

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "phpfile.php",
        data: {desks:desks}
    })
});
```

**PHP**

```
$desks = $_POST("desks");
$sql = "UPDATE desks SET desk_x=$desks->x,desk_y=$desks->y WHERE desk_id=$desks->id";
$conn->query($sql);
```